# How to call stored procedure in WebApi 2 Controller with action using Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2019

I need to build a Web API v2 with Entity Framework controller where I can pass json in "jsonpass" parameter and "todo" parameter from [FromURI].

So that json has to be going into stored procedure. When I pass json as parameter stored procedure defines the columns for itself without needing of specifying columns.

```
create or alter procedure [dbo].[save_dynamicforms] 
    (@todo varchar(200), 
     @jsonpass varchar(max))
```

Comment: Ok.  So are you trying to ask a question?

Comment: This question feels incomplete. What you mean the Stored Procedure defines the columns itself? A Stored procedures returns what ever columns you defined it to.

Comment: i mean i need to pass JSON as a parameter into stored procedure .when i tried passing i'm getting error saying string cannot be converted.